# TypeScript - How to get variable from namespace dynamically?

Tags: typescript

Is it possible to get variable from typescript namespace by string value?
I would like to do something more less like this. From namespace:

```
namespace Keys {
    const string key1 = 'x';
    const string key2 = 'y';
}
```

get value by string:

```
function getKey(suffix: string) {
    return Keys[`key${suffix}`];
}
```

For call `getKey('1')` it should return `x`.

The code above does not work. I came up only with an idea of creating a helper function in that namespace. Is there any other way?

**EDIT**

After adding `export` to values there was a problem with:
`element implicitly has an 'any' type because type 'typeof' has no index signature`. Casting explicitly to `any` was the solution to that. I couldn't find better way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to `export` the values in order for them to be accessible outside the namespace.

```js
namespace Keys {
    export const key1 = 'x';
    export const key2 = 'y';
}
```

The rest of your solution looks good.